# Java list in Greenfoot

Tags: java, list, greenfoot

I am trying to access a specific element in a java list of Greenfoot (http://www.greenfoot.org/).

`getObjects(Object.class).get(0).getPosition();`

Object is my own class. It has a method named `public float getPosition() { ... }`

getObjects() returns a java.util.List.
Documentation of Greenfoot -> World: http://www.greenfoot.org/files/javadoc/

But the error is: `cannot find symbol - method getPosition()`

Comment: How have you declared the `List` ?

Comment: It is already declared by Greenfoot. For example, I can  call getObjects(Object.class).get(0); without problems.

Comment: It would appear you're saying that list contains Object instances via passing `Object.class`. There's no such method in `Object`

Comment: http://www.greenfoot.org/files/javadoc/greenfoot/World.html

Comment: Please don't create a class called `Object`. Please. Nobody will think that it is your class, and, as names goes, it is totally non-descriptive.

Comment: Actually, it should represent a mass object in space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://www.greenfoot.org/files/javadoc/greenfoot/World.html#getObjects(java.lang.Class)):

> Get all the objects in the world, or all the objects of a particular class.
>
> **If a class is specified as a parameter, only objects of that class (or its subclasses) will be returned.**

Since you have passed the `Class` as `Object.class`. It is returning a `List` of `java.lang.Object` class and hence you get that error .You need to rename your class.

```
((yourClassName)getObjects(yourClassName.class).get(0)).getPosition();
```